# Disable the "Chime" sound with Ctrl-F in a Memo

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, keypreview

I am using a TReplaceDialog and the following to catch key to launch the dialog, but Windows 8.1 keeps going "Ding" when I use it. How can I stop that chime? I have tried messing with the Form KeyPreview but still get that chime. Same for using the ShortCut (Ctrl-R) with the Popup menu Item "pupuFindReplaceText"

Also, I get the chime when I use the Tab to move from the "Find text" edit to the "Replace text" Edit within the dialog. Or, is this just a feature of 8.1?

```
if Shift = [ssCtrl] then
begin
  if Char(Key) in ['F','f','R','r'] then
    puFindReplaceTextClick(Sender);
  Key:=0;
end else
begin
end;
```

Comment: What event is this code from? You've posted it out of context, with no details about where it's being used.

Comment: This is much broader. Steps to reproduce; having system sounds on, add a memo to a form, add no code, run the app., focus the memo and press some keyboard shortcuts (like e.g. CTRL + R, CTRL + A etc.).

Comment: @TLama: You're right. It happens on Win7 with the steps you describe as well; it's not a Windows 8.1 issue. (It also doesn't happen if you replace the TMemo with a TRichEdit, with no other changes.)

Comment: @user2175495, assign a standard `TSearchReplace` action with a shortcut for your popup menu and you should be fine (not for the unassigned shortcuts though).

Comment: I'd personally do this with an action and its shortcut

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `OnKeyDown`,  use `OnKeyPress`:

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = ^F then
  begin
    // Do something;
    Key := #0;
  end;
end;
```